# Буква Ё в тексте (на конкретном примере)

Tags: орфоэпия, е-или-ё

«Светильник тела есть око; итак, если око твое будет чисто, то и все тело твое будет светло; а если оно будет худо, то и тело твое будет темно. Итак, смотри: свет, который в тебе, не есть ли тьма?»

«Если же тело твое всё светло и не имеет ни одной темной части, то будет светло всё так, как бы светильник освещал тебя сиянием.»

В этих цитатах (Лк. 11, 34—36) при многих номинальных Ё — лишь одно, а другие справедливо заменены. Но часть, думается, неоправданно. Это так?

Answer (score 1):

Употребление буквы Ё

http://orthographia.ru/orfografia.php?sid=10#pp10

В обычных печатных текстах буква ё употребляется **выборочно**. Рекомендуется употреблять ее в следующих случаях.
1. Для предупреждения неправильного опознания слова, напр.: **всё**, нёбо, лётом, совершённый (в отличие соответственно от слов **все**, небо, летом, совершенный)...

Comment: А что по конкретному случаю? по конкретным словам?

Comment: Наверное, слово "всё", здесь Ё  во всех текстах желательно обозначать.

Answer (score 0):

Если для современного прочтения (по-церковной традиции такой текст, видимо, весь произносится через "е"), то имеющиеся расстановки "точек" выглядят обоснованными - в интересах исключения неоднозначности при первом чтении. "Темно" - изначально с "е" ("ё" появляется только в приставках "тёмно-"), а оба случая "всё" исключают неоднозначность чтения ("всё" или "все"), поскольку непрочитанное следующее слово может оказаться таким, что потребует иного прочтения "проблемной" буквы (... тело твое все [видят]; будет светло все [дни]). В словах же, где "ё" заменено на "е", возможен только один вариант прочтения.

Comment: Кроме наречия и предикатива ТЕМНО ещё и краткое прилагательное — тёмен, тёмно, тёмна.

Comment: Исходил из лермонтовского "Его грядущее  — иль пусто, иль темнО", В словарях пока попадалось только "тёмно-".

Comment: Темна ноченька, не спится,
Выйду к речке на лужок.
Распоясала зарница
В пенных струях поясок.